# i want to make user authentication without using IdentityUser

Tags: c#, asp.net, api

I am trying to make a user based authentication without using IdentityUser and UserManager, i made an attribute that is a bool attribute in the user model called IsAdmin, but the problem is im not really sure how can i implement that within my api's, i have a complaint method that retrieves all the complaints sent by the user and only the admin can do that, i did his

```
 public  List<Complaint> AllComplaint()
        {
            var ifAdmin = _context.Users.FirstOrDefault(p=>p.IsAdmin);

            var result = _context.Complaints.ToList();
            return result;
        }
```

this is the repository for the complaints, i registered using a non admin user and it still gets the complaints, although the IsAdmin is set to false.
i want to know does this even do anything or does it even check whether the user is an admin or not?

i registered using a non admin user and it still gets the complaints, although the IsAdmin is set to false.
i want to know does this even do anything or does it even check whether the user is an admin or not?

Comment: Shouldn’t you do something else if `ifAdmin` is false, like return `Unauthorized`?

Comment: You need to know if the logged in user is an Admin. You are only checking if there are any Admins in the database. Why avoid using the features of Identity?